# Get Tweets with Pictures using twitter search api

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-search

Is it possible to get tweets which contain photos?  I am currently using [twitter search api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) and getting all the tweets having entity details by setting include_entities=true.  I see picture details under media object but is there anyway to filter and get tweets objects which just have these media items.  Or is there anyway in Twitter4j to do this query?

Answer (score 17):

There is no specific way to specify that I need only photos or videos but you can filter the results based on `filter:links` or `filter:images` or `filter:videos` in your query along with `include_entities=true`.

For Example: To get the tweets that contain links since `2012-01-31`, you query should have `include_entities` parameter as well as `filter:links` as shown as follows:

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3Agoogle%20since%3A2012-01-31%20filter%3Alinks&include_entities=true"
```

As your need is to filter your tweets based on images/photos, I think you should use `filter:images`.

An example of your case would look like:

```
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3Agoogle%20since%3A2012-01-31%20filter%3Aimages&include_entities=true"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Search using filter:images doesn't return any results.  The sample google url in sample above does not return tweets containing images even though there are tweets from google which have images. Am i missing something?  I removed filter:images and it returns tweets, some of which have images.

Comment: ok i figured it out.  filter:images only returns images that are not uploaded directly thru twitter a.k.a images having url starting from pic.twitter.com.  so i modified my query to following: 'https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=pic.twitter.com%20OR%20filter%3Aimages%20from%3Agoogle%20since%3A2012-01-31&include_entities=true'

Comment: Works using latest Twitter API ?

Comment: filter=images&include_entities=true works like a charm, thank you

Answer (score 2):

With Latest twitter API I couldn't get filters work and I couldn't find either any explanation in their docs. Althought you can get all the tweets and then parse only the media ones. You can fire this if inside your parsing script:

```
if(this.entities.media != null){
  //Parse the tweet
}
```

This is not the best solution but the worst part comes to twitter who's giving you more information and using more of its own resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the lastest twitter API you can do it in the ConfigurationBuilder instance, before creating the Twitter instance:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(false);
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(API_KEY);
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(API_SECRET);
cb.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(SECRET_KEY);
// enabling include_entities parameters
cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);
Twitter twitterInstance = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
```

Also, after enabling the entities, in the search string you have to had the condition "filter:images".

```
List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
keywords.add("#pet");
keywords.add("cat");
// String.join for Java 8
String twitterSearchString = "((" + String.join(" OR ", keywords) + ")";
// adding the filter condition
twitterSearchString  += " AND filter:images)";
Query q = new Query(twitterSearchString);
```

And you will get just results with images (tested with twitter4j-core 4.0.4).

Answer (score 0):

For filter in twitter API you can check official document for latest version as on date Apr 02 2019

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators.html