# How to find only tweets with images/media?

Tags: image, rest, search, twitter

Is it possible via the new Twitter API (preferably REST API, but I'd be as happy with the Streaming API) to find public tweets from any user containing specific search string and an image (or any other kind of media), without having to later manually filter out tweets without images from the returned data? How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter does have an undocumented & unsupported `filter:images` feature that you can read more about in this question: [Get Tweets with Pictures using twitter search api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920851/get-tweets-with-pictures-using-twitter-search-api)