# Get user media (photos) only - Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

Using the Twitter API V1.1 is it possible to just retrieve the photos that a user has posted?

I can see that one way to do this is to pull a user's timeline with `include_entities=true` and search for the photos that way. But that seems like an extremely cumbersome way around, and prone to problems.

For example, we can pull the last 15 tweets and display them, and we know, for sure, that we will always get 15 tweets.

But for just photos, if we were to even pull 100 tweets at a time, we can not be guaranteed that it will contain, say, 15 photos, or even that it will contain any photos at all.

So perhaps I'm clutching at straws here hoping that there is some way to do this that the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and [Dev Discussions](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3005) doesn't know.

I'm looking for a PHP example.

Comment: I dug through all the API docs and I don't see a way. It seems like grabbing a users' feed and iterating through them looking for a media entity is the only way possible right now.

Answer (score 3):

**This might be helpful**: [Get Tweets with Pictures using twitter search api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920851/get-tweets-with-pictures-using-twitter-search-api)

I did a little research and it's possible to get tweets containing only photos, but I am not sure if it shows all tweets photos posted by user.

**Example with using [Twitter-php](https://github.com/vojant/Twitter-php)**

```
require_once 'Twitter-php/RestApi.php';

$consumerKey = 'YOUR CONSUMER KEY';
$consumerSecret = 'YOUR CONSUMER SECRET';
$accessToken = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
$accessTokenSecret = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET';

$twitter = new \TwitterPhp\RestApi($consumerKey,$consumerSecret,$accessToken,$accessTokenSecret);
$connection = $twitter->connectAsApplication();
$tweets = $connection->get('search/tweets', array('q'=>'from:nasa filter:images','include_entities'=>1));
```

This example code should return NASA tweets containing images.