# Get only tweets with Pictures using twitter search api

Tags: twitter

This question has already been asked there : [Get Tweets with Pictures using twitter search api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920851/get-tweets-with-pictures-using-twitter-search-api)

*But it's obsolete now : the new Twitter API doesn't allow the answer provided.*

In a nutshell : **I'm trying, in Ajax, to retrieve tweets with a particular hashtag that contains a media (image)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rather depends on the source of the images that you want to find.  You are best of searching for the URL of the image directly.

If you're looking for images uploaded directly to Twitter with the hashtag "#nice", do a search for `twimg%20%26%20%23nice` (that's "twimg & #nice").

You could also include `flickr` or any other image sharing service.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the only clever way to do this. For test purposes, I tried 'myquery filter:images' as my q param to the API. Works fine too.